# TypeScript package management

Tags: typescript

Looks like TypeScript has a nice module system, however does this replace the need for something like requirejs? In other words, when you "compile" a typescript package does it handle all the dependency resolution for you? Examples would be appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TypeScript does not have a runtime module loader. You will still need to provide a module loader to use at runtime, e.g. require js. TypeScript supports generating JavaScript code compatable with either commonJS (for node.js scripts) and AMD loaders (e.g. requireJS). To specify which one to use pass in the "--module " switch to the compiler with either "amd" or "commonjs".

Here is how you export a module in TypeScript:

```
export module depModule { 
    export class A { 
    }
}
```

and here is the generated JavaScript code with --module amd switch:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    (function (depModule) {
        var A = (function () {
            function A() { }
            return A;
        })();
        depModule.A = A;
    })(exports.depModule || (exports.depModule = {}));
})
```

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript can emit code that will work with both AMD-compatible dependency loaders like requirejs or commonjs environments like Node. You can control this with the --module option to the compiler. The compiler itself doesn't handle dependency resolution at runtime, that's up to you to work out, but it does attempt resolve dependencies at compile time so it can give you type information.

You can see examples of projects that use modules in the test directory at CodePlex, [this one](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/09ec53d6c21d#tests/projects/relative%20-%20global/consume.ts) for example. The output of compiling these test projects are .js files that will be loadable either with, for example, requirejs (if you pass --module amd) or Node (if you pass --module commonjs).

Answer (score 2):

If your application will be composed only by typescript modules / files it is possible to not use module loaders or other dependency management. You will need to include all dependencies with comment references and use the --out option of the compiler. Eg:

```
tsc --out compiled.js app.ts
```

This will put in compiled.js the generated js for app.ts and all its dependencies, including dependencies of dependencies. The resulting file can then be included directly in the html file with the script tag. It can also be minified. Module loading on runtime is not supported